# QGIS constrain move by vertex along an x or y axis

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, vertices

In QGIS, is there a way to constrain a 'move by vertex' along the x or y axis?

In the picture below, I would like to constrain the edit movement along the y-axis  as shown in the bold red dashed line. (THIS IS WHAT I WANT.)

The default 'floaty' behavior is shown by the thin red line & NOT what I want in this case.

[image: QGIS move by vertex constrained to y-axis]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can enable the **Advanced digitizing tools** whilst editing. When enabled, there is an active function which *snaps* the selected vertices to the nearest common angle. You can open the advanced tools from the menubar:

```
View > Panels > Advanced Digitizing Panel
```

Click the left-most icon to ensure it is enabed and set the common snapping angle:

[image: Advanced digitizing panel]

---

Then use the **Node tool** (or **Vertex tool** if using QGIS 3.0), select the vertices and move the cursor vertically whilst staying close to the 90 degree angle:

[image: Vertically]

You can do the same horizontally:

[image: Horizontally]

---

*Note: the layer must be in a **projected CRS** in order to use the Advanced Digitizing Tool*.

*Tested on QGIS 3.0 for Win7 64-bit.*

Comment: @cm1 - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)